# Answer has to contain at least 2 - 3 items from array

Tags: c#

I am making a small programming to help me learn for school.
It involves a question, an array with possible answers.
But the way i solve it now is that if the answer contains any of the key-words from the array the question is marked as correct. Which is not really true.
I would need at least 3 words from the array to assume someone has a correct answer. How can is solve this better ?

```
Console.WriteLine("Was versteht man unter Vollmachten ?");
string answerUser = Console.ReadLine();



string[] answer = {"Recht eines Mitarbeiters", "Namen", "Rechung", "Betriebs Rechtsgeschäfte", "Abzuschliesen"};

if (answer.Any(answerUser.Contains))
{
 Console.WriteLine("Correct");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of checking if just any elements match the condition:

```
if (answer.Any(answerUser.Contains))
```

Check if the count of elements matching the condition is greater than or equal to 3:

```
if (answer.Count(answerUser.Contains) >= 3)
```